# How to treat future requirements in terms of TDD

Tags: tdd, nunit, requirements, organization

While attempting to adopt more TDD practices lately on a project I've run into to a situation regarding tests that cover future requirements which has me curious about how others are solving this problem.

Say for example I'm developing an application called SuperUberReporting and the current release is 1.4. As I'm developing features which are to be included in SuperUberReporting 1.5 I write a test for a new file export feature that will allow exporting report results to a CSV file. While writing that test it occurs to me that the feature to support exports to some other formats are slated for later versions 1.6, 1.7, and 1.9 which are documented in a issue tracking software. Now the question that I'm faced with is whether I should write up tests for these other formats or should I wait until I actually implement those features? This question hits at something a bit more fundamental about TDD which I would like to ask more broadly.

Can/should tests be written up front as soon as requirements are known or should the degree of stability of the requirements somehow determine whether a test should be written or not?

More generally, how far in advance should tests be written? Is it OK to write a test that will fail for two years until the that feature is slated to be implemented? If so then how would one organize their tests to separate tests that are required to pass versus those that are not *yet* required to pass? I'm currently using NUnit for a .NET project so I don't mind specifics since they may better demonstrate how to accomplish such organization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing TDD properly, you will have a continuous integration server (something like Cruise Control or TeamCity or TFS) that builds your code and runs all your tests every time you check in. If any tests fail, the build fails.

So no, you don't go writing tests in advance. You write tests for what you're working on today, and you check in when they pass.

Failing tests are noise. If you have failing tests that you know fail, it will be much harder for you to notice that another (legitimate) failure has snuck in. If you strive to always have all your tests pass, then even *one* failing test is a big warning sign -- it tells you it's time to drop everything and fix that bug. But if you always say "oh, it's fine, we always have a few hundred failing tests", then when real bugs slip in, you don't notice. You're negating the primary benefit of having tests.

Besides, it's silly to write tests now for something you won't work on for years. You're delaying the stuff you should be working on now, and you're wasting work if those future features get cut.

Comment: While I agree and approached with this same attitude at first, I can see the benefit of establishing tests as a form of requirements. So in my example if I could decorate my tests for requirements for version 1.7 differently such as a [NotYetRequired] attribute that would be a great way of keeping track of this stuff or even designating different developers as test writers who are closer to the requirements and other developers who are making those tests pass.

Comment: You're not talking about TDD anymore. TDD and unit tests will be done by the developers as they write the code; if you try to write those unit tests now, they won't even compile, because the objects they're testing haven't been created yet. You're talking about executable requirements, which are more typically done in a different tool like Fit or Spec# or MSpec. That's fine (apart from potential wasted effort doing it so far in advance), but it's something to keep very much apart from your TDD and your unit tests. Totally different level of abstraction.

Comment: (Part of the reason for separate tools is that tools like MSpec have a way to say "there's going to be a test for this, but I haven't fleshed it out yet, so don't try to run it and show my build as failing" -- much more well-suited to high-level requirements like you're talking about.)

Comment: +1. Another reason not to write too many tests up front for TDD is that you are going to encounter problems when you attempt the refactoring step after you finally get around to implementing a feature that passes a test. If you write 20 failing tests that rely on a non-existent class design that you think will suit the problem, them you implement the feature and realise that you need to change that design, you now have to change all of the tests. Without the support of the IDE refactoring tools.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a lot of experience with TDD (just started recently), but I think while practicing TDD, tests and actual code go together. Remember Red-Green-Refactor. So I would write just enough tests to cover my current functionality. Writing tests upfront for future requirements might not be a good idea.

Maybe someone with more experience can provide a better perspective.

Comment: Exactly. In orthodox Extreme Programming, you should never have more than one failing test at a time. You write a test for a new feature, see that it fails, then fix it by implementing the feature. Then you move on to the next feature. The idea is to move in the smallest possible steps.

Answer (score 0):

Tests for future functionality can *exist* (I have BDD specs for things I'll implement later), but should either (a) not be run, or (b) run as non-error "pending" tests.

The system isn't expected to make them pass (yet): they're not valid tests, and should not stand as a valid indication of system functionality.

Comment: That's along the line of what I was thinking. Are there common conventions for handling this within popular testing frameworks (ex. NUnit)? I would be interested to know if I could avoid some pitfalls by drawing on the wisdom in the crowd on this matter.

Comment: @jpierson Don't know about NUnit; sorry :) I'd be surprised if there wasn't some way to skip a test or group of tests, though.

Comment: NUnit has an Ignore attribute that can be placed on a test (or fixture I believe.) NUnit will skip those tests when running.

Comment: Not sure about NUnit, but in PHPUnit, we have a feature for marking a test as 'Incomplete' (so neither pass nor fail). While running your testsuites, it will exactly show how many tests are incomplete

Comment: One option in addition to the NUnit Ignore attribute is the Category attribute, to which you can pass a string describing any arbitrary category name which you prefer.  You should probably use whichever option best distinguishes the pending tests from the failing tests, considering the reasoning Joe White gave in his answer.